# How to count cell numbers based on a set of numbers

Tags: excel

I am looking for a function which counts how many numbers in a range of cells are in the set of numbers

For example I have the set of numbers(1,2,3) and my cells contains 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 5 | 3 , the count should return 4

I have tried using countif but no success, I would like to have an excel function Ex.: =countif(A1:D5,...)

Comment: How *exactly* is the data in the cell structured? Is it delimitted by a pipe as you show above or could it also be a comma or space?

Comment: It is separated by the cell, each number stay in one cell @Remnant

Comment: Ok. So you want a formula where you pass in a range of cells and the number set e.g. `=Formula("A1:A5", {1,2,3})`?

Comment: @Remnant Yes then it will count

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about this?  Assume data is in range `A1:D5` and you want to count cells with a value of 1, 2 or 3:

```
=SUM(COUNTIF(A1:D5, {"1","2","3"}))
```

Comment: Excel says the formula is invalid. Is {"1","2","3"} correct? I suspect that it works only for the excel english version.

Comment: @Rafeal - This worked for me in Excel 2003 (english version). What version you using?

Comment: Excel 2010 (portuguese version). The function names are translated, I dont know if the set of number must be bit different. I will install english version and try it.

Comment: In Portuguese version I imagine you need semi-colons rather than commas....and you shouldn't need quotes in any version (for numbers) so try `=SUM(COUNTIF(A1:D5;{1;2;3}))`

Comment: @barryhoudini You are alright thanks! Is there any way to reference cells that contains the number instead of numbers inside the formula?

Comment: Yes, if the numbers are in F1:F3 you can use this version `=SUM(COUNTIF(A1:D5;F1:F3))` but that now requires "array entry" with CTRL+SHIFT+ENTER so suggest SUMPRODUCT in place of SUM for a "regular" formula, i.e. `=SUMPRODUCT(COUNTIF(A1:D5;F1:F3))`

Answer (score 0):

I hope my pseudo-code would be understandable

```
int count(int *set, int set_size, int *cells, int cells_size)
{
    int v = 0;

    // For every number in set
    for(int i = 0; i < set_size; ++i)
    {
        // Loop through every number in cells
        for(int j = 0; j < cells_size; ++j)
        {
            // If number in cells equals number in set, increment v
            if(cells[j] == set[i])
            {
                v++;
            }
        }
    }

    // Result is in v, return it
    return v;
}
```

Of course you can optimize a bit with using better containers than just arrays and sizes of them, but I hope you get the basics from this.

Note I used C-like language for pseudo-code, if anything is unclear I can explain further.

Comment: Hi, I would like a excel function, Dont you know how to do using excel function?

Comment: Personally I'd do it with macro, but ...

you can actually use =(COUNTIF(A1:A6,F1) + COUNTIF(A1:A6,F2) + COUNTIF(A1:A6,F3))

assuming A1:A6 holds {1|2|3|4|5|3} and F1:F3 holds set to count {1|2|3} it will return you 4